# "ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a beginner in using Asp.net MVC5, I currently doing my project.

It referring to "var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();"
Here is my code:

```
public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
{
    string conString = "Server= EJ ; Database=OnlineShopDb ; Integrated Security=SSPI";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.UserTb where UserName=@UserName and PassWord=@PassWord");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
    con.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you pass the connection to the command...?

Comment: You are not disposing of your connections properly. What if there's an exception? Now you're leaking resources. Learn about the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern.

Comment: I wonder what the Connection property that has not been initialized is???  If only there were a wealth of documentation available somewhere about the SqlCommand class.  Possibly somewhere accessible over the internet.  Wow, that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your connection in a `using` statement, and then pass it in as the second parameter of your `SqlCommand` constructor:

```
var query = "Select * from whatever";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();
    // etc
}
```

Comment: @EjGenito It should also be noted that once you've switched to `using` statements, you will no longer need to manually close or dispose your connections. It will handle that for you, even in the event of an unhandled exception.